# Submitted a post request in postman and only 4 entities mapped(including the primary key)

Tags: java, json, post, jdbc, postman

I recently tried sending a post request via postman and not everything mapped correctly. Despite the fact that I had values set for each attribute within the json file it only mapped values to 4 attributes. The other attributes were marked as null. It also did something weird where it displayed the values for the other entities in my database. I am assuming the issue is some way linked to this. Below I have a screenshot of before and the response I got back when I submitted the request. I also added the model,service and controller classes as well as the xml file I converted to JSON for the Student Entity. Any help at all I would appreciate greatly.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUz4R.jpg)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW6O5.jpg)

Student Model Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Student implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    @XmlElement(name = "studentID")
    private Long studentID;
    @Column(name = "email")
    @XmlElement(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    @XmlElement(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @XmlElement(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "dob")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd")
    @XmlElement(name = "dob")
    private Date dob;
    @Column(name = "home_phone")
    @XmlElement(name = "homePhone")
    private String homePhone;
    @Column(name = "mobile")
    @XmlElement(name = "mobile")
    private String mobile;
    @Column(name = "first_day_on_campus")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd")
    @XmlElement(name = "firstDayOnCampus")
    private Date firstDayOnCampus;

    @Column(name = "student_level")
    @XmlElement(name = "studentLevel")
    private String studentLevel;
    @Column(name = "gpa")
    @XmlElement(name = "gpa")
    private double gpa;
    @Column(name = "sat_score")
    @XmlElement(name = "satScore")
    private int satScore;
    @Column(name = "act_score")
    @XmlElement(name = "actScore")
    private int actScore;
    @Column(name = "last_login_date")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd")
    @XmlElement(name = "lastLoginDate")
    private Date lastLoginDate;
    @Column(name = "last_login_ip")
    @XmlElement(name = "lastLoginIP")
    private String lastLoginIP;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Admissions> admissions;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Attendance> attendance;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<CourseRoster> courseRoster;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<ExamResultsStudentView> examResultsStudentView;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<ExamResultsTeacherView> examResultsTeacherView;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<GradeLevel> gradeLevel;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<HomeworkAssignmentResultsStudentView> homeworkAssignmentResultsStudentView;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<HomeworkAssignmentResultsTeacherView> homeworkAssignmentResultsTeacherView;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<StudentDashboardSnapshotInfo> studentDashboardSnapshotInfo;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<ReportCard> reportCard;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<StudentDirectory> studentDirectory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<StudentHasParent> studentHasParent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<StudentSchedule> studentSchedule;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<TeacherViewAllGradesInCourse> teacherViewAllGradesInCourse;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Transcripts> transcripts;

//constructors
//Getters and Setters
```

Student Service Class

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    //Create
    public Student createStudent(Student std) {
        return studentRepository.save(std);
    }

    //Read
    public List<Student> getStudent() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    //Update
    public Student updateStudent(Long studentID, Student studentInformation) {
        Student std = studentRepository.findById(studentID).get();
        std.setEmail(studentInformation.getEmail());
        std.setPassword(studentInformation.getPassword());
        std.setLastName(studentInformation.getLastName());
        std.setFirstName(studentInformation.getFirstName());
        std.setDob(studentInformation.getDob());
        std.setHomePhone(studentInformation.getHomePhone());
        std.setMobile(studentInformation.getMobile());
        std.setFirstDayOnCampus(studentInformation.getFirstDayOnCampus());
        std.setGpa(studentInformation.getGpa());
        std.setSatScore(studentInformation.getSatScore());
        std.setActScore(studentInformation.getActScore());
        std.setLastLoginDate(studentInformation.getLastLoginDate());
        std.setLastLoginIP(studentInformation.getLastLoginIP());

        return studentRepository.save(std);
    }

    //Delete
    public void deleteStudent(Long studentID) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(studentID);
    }
}
```

Student Controller Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/studentsApi")
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    StudentService stdService;

    @Autowired
    StudentRepository stdRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "students", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Student createStudents(@RequestBody Student std) {
        return stdService.createStudent(std);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "students", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Student> readStudents() {
        return stdService.getStudent();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "students/{stdId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Student updateStudents(@PathVariable(value = "stdId") Long id, @RequestBody Student stdDetails) {
        return stdService.updateStudent(id, stdDetails);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "students/{stdId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void deleteStudents(@PathVariable(value = "stdId") Long id) {
        stdService.deleteStudent(id);
    }

}
```

Student XML File

```
<student>
        <studentID>17365429</studentID>
        <email>charliebrown@gmail.com</email>
        <password>goodgrief72</password>
        <lastName>Brown</lastName>
        <firstName>Charlie</firstName>
        <dob>2008-10-09</dob>
        <homePhone>5053152585</homePhone>
        <mobile>2025550186</mobile>
        <firstDayOnCampus>2022-09-11</firstDayOnCampus>
        <studentLevel>Freshman</studentLevel>
        <gpa>0.0</gpa>
        <satScore>0</satScore>
        <actScore>0</actScore>
        <lastLoginDate>2022-06-06</lastLoginDate>
        <lastLoginIP>165.220.147.72</lastLoginIP>
    </student>
```

Comment: wondering how do you have your payload definition, according to your json, seems to me that you have an object inside another object... could you share the DTO definition by chance?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey @vcg, I just added in my model, service, and controller class as well as the xml file. I think the issue may have to do with the model class mappings of OneToMany relationships. Let me know your thoughts on what the issue might be as soon as you get a moment. I appreciate you looking into this for me!

Comment: do you have any exceptions when you try to save the student information? or maybe a GitHub repo to take a look?

Comment: Hey @vcg, no exceptions thrown. Here is my github repo -> https://github.com/barroodc/StudentManagementSystem

Comment: @vcg I again wanted to say I appreciate you looking at this for me. I've been scratching my head and I feel like its a really small mistake. I just can't see it lol

Comment: So I did a quick POST test sending a new student... it seems working for me, I believe what you need is just review the correct payload to send over your endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to review the correct payload to be sent to the endpoint.. here is an example that worked for me using your code:

```
{
"studentID": 1,
"email": "email@example.com",
"password": "pwdexample**",
"lastName": "user last name",
"firstName": "firts name",
"dob": "1990/01/01",
"homePhone": "0000000000",
"mobile": "000000000",
"firstDayOnCampus": "2022/01/01",
"studentLevel": "test"
}
```

and here is the response from the server

```
{
"studentID": 1,
"email": "email@example.com",
"password": "pwdexample**",
"lastName": "user last name",
"firstName": "firts name",
"dob": "1990/01/01",
"homePhone": "0000000000",
"mobile": "000000000",
"firstDayOnCampus": "2022/01/01",
"studentLevel": "test",
"gpa": 0,
"satScore": 0,
"actScore": 0,
"lastLoginDate": null,
"lastLoginIP": null,
"admissions": null,
"attendance": null,
"courseRoster": null,
"examResultsStudentView": null,
"examResultsTeacherView": null,
"gradeLevel": null,
"homeworkAssignmentResultsStudentView": null,
"homeworkAssignmentResultsTeacherView": null,
"studentDashboardSnapshotInfo": null,
"reportCard": null,
"studentDirectory": null,
"studentHasParent": null,
"studentSchedule": null,
"teacherViewAllGradesInCourse": null}
```

Comment: Hey @VCG yes let me try that now. I saw you were able to communicate with my database just now. Also, I was able to get rid of the additional fields by adding the jsonignore tag. I will let you know if it works!

Comment: it worked! Thank you so much for your help. I also changed the date format from yyyy-dd-mm to yyyy/dd/mm which helped as well.

Comment: sounds good, np